# No carga imagen en parallax con Materialize

Tags: javascript, html, materialize, parallax

Ando con un problema que no me carga la imagen en el parallax, ya probé de todo, si alguno me ayuda sería genial, inserto:

HTML:

```
<div class="parallax-container center valign-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 white-text">
        <h2 class="teal-text teal-text lighten-2">Calculadora de Superficies y Volumenes</h2>
        <p>Un programa diseñado para calcular la superficie y volumenes de distintas figuras geometricas.
        </p>
        <a href="index.html" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large teal lighten-2">Superficies</a>
        <a href="" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large teal lighten-2">Volúmenes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax">
    <img src="imagenes/fondoparallax.jpeg">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parallax-container {
  height: 400px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parallax').parallax();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Si revisas [las clases CSS de Materialize](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.css) podrás ver que aplica las siguientes propiedades a las imágenes dentro de un contenedor `.parallax`:

```
.parallax-container .parallax img {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Parece un poco ilógico que se aplique [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) con valor `0` por defecto a estas imágenes, como sabrás lo que hace esta propiedad es aplicar transparencia a un elemento, por lo cual será invisible. Incluso se ha debatido este comportamiento en varios *["issues"](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/210#issuecomment-66420932)*

Existen dos soluciones, la primera es casi automática y parece que pasaste por alto:

En tu código estás usando jQuery para llamar la función del `parallax`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.parallax').parallax();
  });
```

Por lo tanto, debes llamar a la librería jQuery en tu proyecto, siempre debe ir primera que la librería JS de Materialize. Con eso bastaría.

En un extraño caso que esta solución no te funcione, o que simplemente no quieras usar jQuery, la segunda solución sería cambiar esta propiedad a valor `1`. Si estás trabajando con la librería en local, tan fácil como buscar la clase `.parallax-container .parallax img` y reemplazar `opacity: 0;` por `opacity: 1;`. Si estás trabajando con CDNs entonces fuerza a que se aplique esta propiedad, así por ejemplo:

```
<div class="parallax">
  <img src="imagenes/fondoparallax.jpeg" style="opacity: 1;">
</div>
```

---

Este sería tu código funcional.

**Primera opción:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.parallax').parallax();
  });
```

```css
.parallax-container {
    height: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- jQuery y Materialize.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>




<div class="parallax-container center valign-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 white-text">
        <h2 class="teal-text teal-text lighten-2">Calculadora de Superficies y Volumenes</h2>
        <p>Un programa diseñado para calcular la superficie y volumenes de distintas figuras geometricas.
        </p>
        <a href="index.html" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large teal lighten-2">Superficies</a>
        <a href="" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large teal lighten-2">Volúmenes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax">
    <img src="https://materializecss.com/images/parallax1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Segunda opción:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax');
    var instances = M.Parallax.init(elems, options);
  });
```

```css
.parallax-container {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Materialize.js SIN jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>




<div class="parallax-container center valign-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 white-text">
        <h2 class="teal-text teal-text lighten-2">Calculadora de Superficies y Volumenes</h2>
        <p>Un programa diseñado para calcular la superficie y volumenes de distintas figuras geometricas.
        </p>
        <a href="index.html" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large teal lighten-2">Superficies</a>
        <a href="" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large teal lighten-2">Volúmenes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax">
    <img src="https://materializecss.com/images/parallax1.jpg" style="opacity: 1;"> <!-- Esta es la 2da solución -->
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Aclaración:

En caso que no vayas a utilizar jQuery, es decir, con la segunda opción, la forma en que debes llamar el `parallax` será así:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax');
    var instances = M.Parallax.init(elems, options);
  });
```